# How to convince someone to use layered security?

Tags: defense, security-by-design

> Layered security, also known as layered defense, describes the
>   practice of combining multiple mitigating security controls to protect
>   resources and data.

How to convince someone to use [layered security](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_security)? While rejecting counterarguments like: "

1. *We already have a rock-solid firewall...*
2. *He always installs all security updates...*
3. *I use HTTPS on all my pages...*

*... that should be enough!"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't always put in every single possible mitigation you can think of.  There is a cost to this.  Security is always a compromise between risk, cost, and usability.

If you are currently in a position where you need to assess the risk of a particular threat, I suggest you take a look at [OWASP's risk rating methodology](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Risk_Rating_Methodology) .

If you follow a rigorous and objective methdology, your peers are more likely to be convinced.  And you have to be open to the possibility that the methodology yields an answer you don't like.